# Why is whatsapp web restricted to google chrome only?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, whatsapp, webchromeclient

Just curious about this, why is whatsapp web restricted to chrome only? Are there any security issues with other browsers or is it something specific to chrome engine  or is it something related to performance or is it the mobile to pc synchronization via gmail that's restricting whatsapp web to chrome browser.
We could have a firefox plugin for whatsapp web

Comment: okay,why the downvote? Please help me correct by specifying the reason. 
Is it not the correct forum? Is it not Programming related?

Comment: I guess only chrome supports GCM..

Answer (score 2):

Most probably because Chrome fully supports Web Real-Time Communication (WebRTC).
I guess the phone is providing data via P2P to the Web API.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC

Comment: Pardon if i am asking a silly question, but the link says, it supports Firefox as well:
Pasting for quick reference:
WebRTC is supported in the following browsers.

Desktop PC
Google Chrome 23
Mozilla Firefox 22

What do we mean by "Chrome fully supports", i could not find any reference here. Please share inputs.